# Obtain the value of the random variable given the cumulative probability (Python)

Tags: python, statistics, probability, distribution, probability-distribution

Here is a quick background information. I am trying to obtain a combined CDF for the linear combination of two lognormal random variables using Monte-Carlo approach and then, invert it to do sampling. Here is the Python code for doing the same:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special


# parameters of distribution 1
mu1 = 0.3108
s1=0.3588

# parameters of distribution 2
mu2=1.2271
s2=0.2313

a = 2
b=3

N_sampling = 10000

kk=0

Y=np.zeros(N_sampling)
X1=np.zeros(N_sampling)
X2=np.zeros(N_sampling)

while(kk<N_sampling):
    F = np.random.rand(2)
    X1[kk]=np.exp(mu1+(2**0.5)*s1*special.erfinv(2*F[0]-1))  # sampling X1 (distribution1) by inverting the CDF
    X2[kk]=np.exp(mu2+(2**0.5)*s2*special.erfinv(2*F[1]-1))  # sampling X2 (distribution2) by inverting the CDF  
    
    Y[kk]=a*X1[kk]+b*X2[kk] # obtain the random variable as a linear combination of X1 and X2
    kk=kk+1
    

# Obtain the CDF of Y

freq, bin_borders = np.histogram(Y, bins=50)    
norm_freq = freq/np.sum(freq)
cdf_Y = np.cumsum(norm_freq)


# obtain the value of Y given the value of cdf_Y
cdf_Y_input=0.5
idx=np.searchsorted(cdf_Y,cdf_Y_input)
Y_out = 0.5*(bin_borders[idx-1]+bin_borders[idx])
```

Questions:

Is there a direct function in scipy to perform this operation ?

In the last line of the code, I am taking the mean value, is there a way I could obtain more accurate values by interpolation, etc ? If so, How do I implement it in Python

Comment: Why are you simulating lognormals? You can just average two cumulative lognormals with scipy. Then invert the function using this: https://pypi.org/project/pynverse/ for your sampling.

Comment: could you please explain how to average two cumulative lognormals with scipy ?

Comment: (lognorm.cdf(1st set of parameters) + lognorm.cdf(2nf set of parameters))/2. Integral of an average is the average of integrals.

Comment: @LevB this is wrong, you don't average CDF, please check my answer

Comment: @Mechanician Is the goal only to do sampling? What I mean to ask is whether the CDF is needed for some other purpose than sampling. Thanks for any info.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to do sampling

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is well-known case when you sum two RVs X+Y, know PDF<sub>X</sub>(x), PDF<sub>Y</sub>(y) and want to know PDF<sub>X+Y</sub>(z). You could use similar approach here, compute PDF and make CDF=d PDF(z)/dz

PDF<sub>aX+bY</sub>(z) = S dy PDF<sub>Y</sub>(y) PDF<sub>X</sub>((z-by)/a) / |a|

where `S` denotes integration.

You could write it directly for CDF

CDF<sub>aX+bY</sub>(z) = S dy PDF<sub>Y</sub>(y) CDF<sub>X</sub>((z-by)/a)

You could compute this integral:

1. Analytically
2. Numerically, using [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html)
3. Do Fourier transform forward and backward, similar to [Convolution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html)
4. Of course, Monte Carlo integration is always an option

UPDATE

Here is the simplest code to get you going

```
import numpy as np
from math import erf

SQRT2 = np.sqrt(2.0)
SQRT2PI = np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)
    
def PDF(x):
    if x <= 0.0:
        return 0.0

    q = np.log(x)
    return np.exp( - 0.5*q*q ) / (x * SQRT2PI)

def CDF(x):
    if x <= 0.0:
        return 0.0

    return 0.5 + 0.5*erf(np.log(x)/SQRT2)    

import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 0.4
b = 0.6

N = 101

z = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, N)
c = np.zeros(N) # CDF of the sum
p = np.zeros(N) # PDF of the sum
t = np.zeros(N) # CDF as integral of PDF

for k in range(1, N):
    zz = z[k]
    ylo = 0.0
    yhi = zz/b

    result = integrate.quad(lambda y: PDF(y) * CDF((zz - b*y)/a), ylo, yhi)
    print(result)
    c[k] = result[0]

    result = integrate.quad(lambda y: PDF(y) * PDF((zz - b*y)/a)/a, ylo, yhi)
    print(result)
    p[k] = result[0]

    t[k] = integrate.trapz(p, z) # trapezoidal integration over PDF


plt.plot(z, c, 'b^') # CDF
plt.plot(z, p, 'r.') # PDF
plt.plot(z, t, 'g-') # CDF as integral over PDF
plt.show()
```

Graph

[image]

Comment: thank you, but sum of two lognormals do not have a closed form analytical solution

Comment: @Mechanician Well, I would look at direct integration first via SciPy. Lower bound is 0, upper bound is fixed as well due to (z-by)/a term.

Comment: thanks a lot , appreciate it. Also, PDF = d/dx ( CDF) , not the otherway around. So CDF will be the integral of PDF

Comment: @Mechanician  `PDF = d/dx ( CDF)` sure, but you'd better integrate it along the CDF. I've updated code and plot

Comment: @Mechanician or you could even integrate PDF along the loop to check if CDF is ok. Code and graph updated

Comment: @Mechanician I posted in another question answer how to do sampling from inverted CDF. YOu might want to look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63449211/scipy-von-mises-distribution-on-a-half-circle/63456201#63456201

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a sample from the sum of 2 lognormal distribution, you do not need a Monte-Carlo scheme.

```
import openturns as ot 
x1 = ot.LogNormal()
x1.setParameter(ot.LogNormalMuSigma()([0.3108, 0.3588, 0.0]))
# in order to convert mu, sigma into mulog and sigmalog

x2 = ot.LogNormal()
x2.setParameter(ot.LogNormalMuSigma()([1.2271, 0.2313, 0.0]))
```

the sum of x1 and x2 is itself a distribution

```
sum = x1+x2
```

you can access its mean `sum.getMean()[0]` (= 1.5379) or its standard deviation `sum.getStandardDeviation()[0]`(= 0.42689241033309544)

and of course, you can get a sample of any size N
For N=5: `sum.getSample(5)`

```
print(sum.getSample(5))
0 : [ 1.29895 ]
1 : [ 1.32224 ]
2 : [ 1.259   ]
3 : [ 1.16083 ]
4 : [ 1.30129 ]
```